# How to retrieve all data when using spring boot JPA hibernate 6 multi-tenant with @TenantId

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate-6.x

When using my admin account to retrieve all data in Hibernate, the tenant_id discriminator is always set, which I want to deactivate dynamically.

How can I do this?
Thanks in advance